# Prove no field exists if $b+d\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

I need to prove no field $K$ exists (with minimum 3 elements) which holds:
$\forall a,c\in K, b,d\in K\setminus\{0\}: b+d\neq 0 \implies\frac a b + \frac c d = \frac{a+c}{b+d}$

I know this can't be true, but I don't know where to start to prove it. Probably my problem is with proving things false in general.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With regards to proving "things false", a good approach is a proof by contradiction. Assume it's true, and see if you can arrive at a contradiction. Frequently, you'll have no idea where to start, and just have to play around with the consequences of that assumption until you find one. Normally it doesn't take long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose for contradiction that the statement held.

If there are at least three elements in the field, then we can find $b\ne 0$, $d\ne 0$, and $b+d\ne 0$, since we could take for example $b=1$, $d\ne 0,-1$. Hence there are some $b,d\ne 0$ with $b+d\ne 0$ such that for all $a$ and $c$ in the field $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$.

Now multiply by $(b+d)bd$, to get $ad(b+d)+cb(b+d)=(a+c)bd = adb+ad^2+cb^2+cbd=abd+cbd$. Cancel $abd$ and $cbd$ to get $ad^2+cb^2=0$, and this is supposed to be true for all $a$ and all $c$. In particular, if $a=0$ and $c\ne 0$, then we have $cb^2=0$, but $c\ne 0$ and $b\ne 0$, so $cb^2\ne 0$. Contradiction.

Comment: There will have to be some mention of where you're using that $K$ has at least three elements.  If $K = \mathbb{F}_2$ then the statement is vacuously true (simply because it's impossible to have $b \ne 0$, $d \ne 0$, $b + d \ne 0$ simultaneously).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Good point, let me edit